# Saved Credit Card option in magento keeps turning back on

Tags: magento, payment

Saved Credit Card option in magento keeps turning back on.
Its No in System -> payment Default in the individual stores but at about the same time daily it goes back to Yes.
Anyone has any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

Was going to guess it was probably an aggressive cache, but the fact that it happens daily at the same time, this is a long shot but I might check my scheduled jobs under system > scheduler > scheduled jobs maybe there is something in there that is telling it to set specific settings or something?  Post an answer if you figure it out!